# Norms and invertibility of a summation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to show that if $X,Y$ are matrices with $X$ invertible and
$$\lVert Y-X\rVert < \lVert X^{-1}\rVert^{-1}$$
then
$$Y^{-1} = X^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (I - YX^{-1})^k,$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix and $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ is the operator norm.

---

We know that the norm satisfies

- the triangle inequality,
- $\lVert X\rVert > 0$ if $X \ne 0$, and
- $\lVert X a\rVert \le \lVert X\rVert |a|$.

I am completely stuck, and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with numerical methods?

Comment: Is there any relation between $X$, $Y$, $A$, and $B$?

Comment: Doesn't a norm usually have $\lVert aX\rVert = |a|\lVert X \rVert$, rather than just an inequality?

Comment: I got rid of $A$ and $B$, since they didn't make sense.

Comment: There is a lot of confusion here. What is meant is that $\lVert X \rVert$ is the induced operator norm for a matrix $X$. The definition of a norm and the properties of the operator norm (including the **in**equality) are entangled.

Comment: @Sharkos, could you edit the question to make it sensible? I have reached the limit of my ability to do so, although I think you'll probably agree that it is better than I found it....

Comment: @dfeuer I'll have a go. It's probably easiest to remove the attempts at definitions, they're fairly well known... But I'll try to leave the gist in.

Comment: sorry I am new to think @Sharkos how you explained it is what I orginially meant.  Thank you and sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to a classic problem no doubt found elsewhere on StackExchange, but possible with a slightly different twist, so I outline the whole method.

Consider
$$Z_m=X^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^m(I-YX^{-1})^k$$

Then, letting $T=YX^{-1}$ and $S=I-T$,
$$YZ_m = T\sum_{k=0}^m(I-T)^k = (I-S)\sum_{k=0}^mS^k = \text{something nice}$$
which I'll let you figure out; hence
$$Z_m = Y^{-1} (\text{something nice})$$

Now also notice that $S=I-YX^{-1}=(X-Y)X^{-1}$ and so you can say something about $\lVert S \rVert$, and also about the behaviour as $m\to\infty$.

Can you see how to put the above together?

Comment: @dfeuer $(I-S)(I+S+S^2+\cdots+S^m) = (I-S)+(S-S^2)+(S^2-S^3)+\cdots$

Comment: Ah, I just figured that out, refreshed, and saw your comment. Plain old geometric series.